# ImageView causes android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled exception

Tags: android, exception, canvas, bitmap, imageview

I'm very occasionally receiving the following exception. It occurs so rarely that I haven't been able to figure out any circumstances that might trigger it -- I've mostly seen it in Flurry exception reports from other users. It could potentially be related to switching out of and back to the activity (e.g. with the Home button), but that's only a guess.

```
class java.lang.RuntimeException    android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled:955 (Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@30095b30)
```

Full LogCat dump here: http://pastebin.com/2RjjgWHH

I've looked through related questions, but none of them seem to apply. The thing is, I'm not manually recycling any bitmaps. I'm not loading large bitmaps or manipulating bitmaps. I have a *single, tiny* `ImageView` icon in my entire app, loaded from an XML layout, and I don't do anything with it programmatically except for switching the containing `LinearLayout` between `VISIBLE` and `GONE`. Basically the only other things in the app are two `WebView`s, a `TextView` and a `ProgressDialog`.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon_a" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" android:focusable="false" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></ImageView>
```

Is there something special you need to do with an `ImageView` to keep it from being recycled, or check and refresh it if recycled, when switching it between `VISIBLE` and `GONE`? Most of the time it works perfectly.

Comment: After running further tests, it seems that it's not even my ImageView causing the problem. Unless the WebView uses ImageViews for something, I guess it's probably related to AdMob code or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception was caused by an advertising SDK, and has been fixed in a recent SDK release.

Comment: Can you provide more details about that? Any link for a bug report or at least which versions are affected by this bug?

Comment: It was the MobClix SDK. The issue was fixed in SDK version 3.1.2.